# Error in uploading data to HDFS Fiware Cosmos global Instance

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I am trying to launch a cosmos instance following this document:http://fiware-cosmos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start_guide_new/index.html.
The first step is executed successfully and i got a access token using which i create a cosmos account acc. to 2nd step and receive this response:
{"organizations": [], "displayName": "varun143", "roles": [], "app_id": "45bed173b2f8482aa15b22556c057112", "isGravatarEnabled": false, "email": "manchandavishal143@gmail.com", "id": "varun143"}.

Now i follow the 3rd step i.e creating a new dir using this command:curl -X PUT "http://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/varun143/testdir?op=MKDIRS&user.name=varun143" -H "X-Auth-token: my acess token" | python -m json.tool and get this response: 
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
No JSON object could be decoded.

then i create a testdata.txt file in my local & write some data in it as per document and run this command:curl -v -X PUT -T testdata.txt "http://storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/varun143/testdir/testdata.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=varun143" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -H "X-Auth-token: my acess token" and get this response attach in this image url:https://imgur.com/uiWU5qr which is not as per document.Now where am i wrong & how to resolve this.Also how can i access cli or GUI  of this instance.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old documentation of cosmos, the current documentation is available here https://github.com/ging/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/doc/manuals/quick_start_guide_new.md. Moreover, you need to send an email with the information that you got in step 2 for that the platform administrator creates your account, you have to consider that currently, we are in summer holidays so the creation of your account maybe suffers some delays. Also is important that you be informed that the cloud platform is only for testing purposes and use only batching processing. As a personal advice, if you don't have a real big data problem, don't try to solve it using big data technologies because you are only adding complexity to solve that problem.

Comment: I have email my fiware lab id to this email 'jamunoz@dit.upm.es' on 6th august.but i have not receive any response as of now.please create my account asap if you can.